# Best Practice : Call a function from chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I'm on a running website, I would like to call one one the functions that is coded in one of the js file of this website, I want to call it from the developer console in chrome, what is the best practice to do it ? I do not want to wait for the website to trigger the function, as it takes way too long. Thank you